# What do I do if drywall screws won't penetrate the studs?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, screws, studs

We have begun a bathroom remodel project.  All the studs were exposed by removing plaster, wood lath and old plastic tile.  We began attempting to install  the ceiling drywall first.  We were able to drive 1-5/8" drywall screws partially in,  just enough to get it up there, but we were totally unable to drive the heads down just below the surface.  (The drywall is 5/8" thick).

I tried removing them and re-inserting, with no success.  I suspect the studs are really hard old-growth wood, believing this house to be 100 years old.  Our next attempt was predrilling, which may have worked but the required drill bit was not long enough to penetrate the wood completely.  We were able to "sink" the screws, except for approximately 1/16", that protrudes above the drywall.  I really don't want to use shorter screws or nails. The drill used was 3/32".

How can I drive the screws to the proper depth?

Comment: What is happening with your drill?  It just stops?  Or does it strip the screws?

Comment: Do you have an impact driver? Not ideal for drywall installation, and there's the possibility of shearing the screw head off, but that's what I'd try myself.

Comment: Sounds like your drill is garbage. I've put up drywall in similar situations and haven't had problems with a fully charged cordless drill. You didn't accidentally have it in reverse did you?

Answer (score 3):

> **I suspect the studs are really hard old-growth wood**

Lubricating screws can really help when driving them into wood. I've seen various lubricants suggested. For exterior projects I've used LM grease and petroleum jelly (vaseline) but I'm not sure if there are any problems using either in your situation.

The other common solution is to drill pilot holes to the expected depth of the screws, but this would be pretty tedious. I usually pick a drill size by holding screw and drill up to the light together and checking that the screw's threads are wider than the drill and that the drill is almost as wide as the core of the screw.

Comment: Another solution -- also a bit of a hassle -- is to drive the screw, back it out, and drive it again (or drive a fresh one if the head was damaged). That lets you start driving it at higher speed, which will often "power through" the place where you stopped last time. Beware of driving the screw all the way through the drywall!

Comment: you can also use a drywall screw bit to help prevent driving it all the way through.

Comment: You need a *sharp* drill bit to get through that old hard pine. Go to the store and buy several brad point bits in the diameter you need. Expect to break a bit or two, and to have to change out the bits when they get dull.

Comment: I just need to patch a small ceiling hole so I can just remove the first screw, lubricate the 2nd one and it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not *snapping* the heads off (torque), your drill just doesn't cut it. If you're *stripping* the heads, you're not pushing hard enough (under powered drills require more pressure to avoid this and also lose torque towards the end, helping you snap the heads off). If the *drywall* pops, use two or more screws 2-3" apart, slowly sinking each one to distribute the load. If the *heads* pop off (tension), use the same procedure only this time, run the screw backwards until it hits the stud, creating a relief. This countersinks the drywall and will help you set the screws with a poor drill or unhappy hard wood. I've had some sections where only deck screws would avail me (+1 for impact drivers). Keshlam mentioned backing it out and driving it again, however I'd toss any screw I backed out that was giving me trouble (careful, they're hot).

Comment: Tip- Hit the dry wall with your fist-palm. If the dry wall moves and dust flies out, you popped the drywall. This screw must be removed and another (or 2) put *near* it. This screw would have popped it's mud plug after a while.

Answer (score 1):

How big an area?  If it is small, can you replace the studs with pine?  Cut the old out with a Sawzall.

You could also use drywall adhesive.

Answer (score 0):

No. Self-tapping screws are for metal. I use 1-1/4 gold screws for drywall. Much stronger than drywall screws. Also buy a drywall screw setter to prevent from driving the screw too far in and breaking the paper surface of the drywall. These are available in a multipack of 4 or singles for less than $5. I second the comments about predtilling in hard wood.

Comment: Please don't respond to other answers in your own answer - that only leads to confusion. You've got plenty of rep to leave a comment, which is where that belonged. Besides, the answer you were responding to wasn't really an answer and will most likely be deleted soon leaving confusion for others reading your answer after the other is gone.

Comment: I use an old bar of soap, preferably slightly soft. It has always worked and been available so I have tried nothing else. It does not take much.